# postfix doesnot work with me

Tags: postfix, mac, gmail

I'm trying to setup postfix server

I wrote this code in vi /etc/postfix/main.cf

```
#Gmail SMTP
relayhost=smtp.gmail.com:587
#Enable SASL authentification in postfix SMTP
smtp_sasl_auth_enable=yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps=hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options=noanonymous
smtp_sasl_mechanism_filter=plain
# Enable TLS i.e. SSL
smtp_use_tls=yes
smtp_tls_security_level=encrypt
tls_random_source=dev:/dev/urandom
```

and I wrote my email and password in this: `vi /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd`

but when  I wrote this command `date | mail -s testing realsharif94@gmail.com nothing happen`

Can anyone help? I will appreciate that.
i got this error

```
CFC581CEDC1      366 Thu Mar 16 23:37:33  reemy@Reems-MacBook-Pro.local
          (connect to smtp.gmail.com[64 Operation timed out)
                                         realsharif94@gmail.com

E42BC1CEE20      366 Thu Mar 16 23:39:06  reemy@Reems-MacBook-Pro.local
     (connect to smtp.gmail.com[ No route to host)
                                         realsharif94@gmail.com
```

Comment: Check your logs.

Comment: This is not your log you added, but your mail queue. I don’t know where postfix logs are stored on MacOS, but on most unices I know, there are in `/var/log/mail.log`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your errors seem to suggest your local network is the possible issue.

There isn't anything obvious to me in the config you share that would be causing this - it seems like your local network might be part of the issue.

You could test, of course: `openssl s_client -connect smtp.gmail.com:587 -starttls smtp`